# why is python reporting wrong time on windows startup?

Tags: python, datetime, time

recently i've been doing a bit of experimenting and found that if i call python's datetime.datetime.now on windows startup running as a service, for the first minute it seems to report the wrong datetime. I believe it was reporting as UTC before going into the right timezone, eg US.

is there a way for python to check to continue only if windows timezone is synced?

how i did this is to run python script as a service using nssm. I did something like this, i'm retyping it so there may be indentation errors:

```
    def testoutput(str):
        with open("c:\\test.log", "a") as f:
          dtime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y-%H:%M:%S")
          f.write("[%s] %s\n" %(dtime, str))


    def main():
        testoutput("starting time..")
        while True:
            testoutput("loop time..")
            time.sleep(1)

    main()
```

so.. when I start windows without logging in, i used another pc to look at the output path. In the file test.log i see something like this :

[07/15/2022-10:57:51] starting time..

[07/15/2022-10:57:52] loop time..

[07/15/2022-10:57:53] loop time..

[07/15/2022-10:57:54] loop time..

[07/15/2022-10:57:55] loop time..

[07/15/2022-03:57:56] loop time..

[07/15/2022-03:57:57] loop time..

even though i'm using the same datetime now, it is showing different time.

edit: i actually did put in some timezone info to see if there's any difference during the loop to see startup vs when the time changed. But i did not see any.

```
local_now = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone()
local_tz = local_now.tzinfo
local_tzname = local_tz.tzname(local_now)
testoutput("current tzname : [%s]" % (local_tzname))
testoutput("current gmtime: [%s]" % (strftime("%z", gmtime())))
```

this will yield me something like..

current tzname : [Pacific Daylight Time]

current gmtime : [-0800]

Comment: what is your time zone?

Comment: datetime.now() returns naive datetime, i.e. Python tries to obtain the local time zone. That is done by calling platform-specific C-libraries, so if the platform does not deliver the right UTC offset for the specified time zone, that's due to the OS not reporting correctly. It's not Python to blame. What you can do to avoid ambiguous results is use `datetime.now(timezone.utc)`.

Comment: -8 UTC time, US pacific

Comment: well, i'm actually trying to use some 3rd party library to do scheduling (https://python-scheduler.readthedocs.io/), but even with the timezoned datetime passed into the library's constructor, i think the library is getting confused due to datetime reporting it differently during init vs scheduled interval

Comment: what do you observe if you log the time zone name as obtained from [tzlocal](https://github.com/regebro/tzlocal) during startup?

Comment: tzlocal? what i did was actually put in some codes to get the timezone in the loop: `local_now = `...i'm not sure how to add codes here i'm just going to edit the main thread to include this info

Comment: follow the link. it's a package that uses the Windows API (on Windows) to obtain the time zone your OS is configured to use.

Comment: i have a feeling the package is using python's datetime, therefore it's just reusing however python was retrieving it. If during startup it's retrieving a timestamp that is in the 'future', then the subsequent ticks will not work until the time after the initial startup time has reached.

Comment: What machine is this? Physical? VM? Container? Is it part of a domain? Windows doesn't arbitrarily start in UTC then change to something else. Something else is happening to change the timezone.

Comment: What account are you using to run your service? I hope it's not `Local System`.

Comment: it's a part of domain, but i believe it is physical and not VM. I did try to run the service with the account vs local system it didn't make any difference too. Yeah, usually i don't even need to worry about having a wrong timestamp but it seemed to behave differently if i don't log into windows. So i thought maybe it is a startup issue..i actually did put in some arbitrary sleep time of about 2 seconds and the issue would go away. However...that's not a guarantee.